# Nexus 5X || HTC Pixel what res folders ? ANDROID

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, dimensions, android-screen-support

I'm trying to set up specific values/drawable folders for all screen devices but it is quite complicated, for example I have 2 similar phones :

HTC Pixel which has resolution 1920x1080 (screen size 5") and,

HTC 5X which has same 1920x1080 resolution (screen size 5,2").

For this type of phones I have values-xxhdpi and also same folder for drawable drawable-xxhdpi. Should this phones use same folders? because on both looks it differently and this is quite strange.

Comment: yes, they will look different since the screen layout also differs in its density pixels or dpi

Comment: so this 2 phones should use same folders ?

Comment: What if I want all this look same ?

Comment: refer here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: If you want to look the same better not use fixed size on height or width, or use sw(smallest width) folder resources

Comment: @SecretCoder now I use different sw folders but still phones use same folder